# Confusing error with AngularJS: Multiple Directive Resource Contention

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

We are having an odd issue in our angular project. The project runs fine on my machine, but when it's run from the development server we get the following error:

> Multiple directives [organizationConfiguration, organizationConfiguration] asking for new/isolated scope on: `<organization-configuration ng-show="tab.id == 'organization'" organization="organization">`

organizationConfiguration is an AngularJS component. The code that is causing the error is below:

```
<organization-configuration ng-show="tab.id == 'organization'"
                            organization="organization">
</organization-configuration>
```

I can't see anything wrong with the code and have no idea where the second scope is coming from. And like I said, the code runs fine on my local machine, but once Jenkins deploys it to the dev server it starts to break. We've been using Jenkins for years without issue so I doubt it's an issue with that.

Thanks

Comment: Look for duplication of the definition of the component. AngularJS accepts multiple definitions of directives with the same name. The $compile service will attempt to  inject all of them into an element. It works with `ngModel` and other directives that have no scope, but it won't work for components with isolate scope.

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss to close the "organization-configuration" tag properly? I could see you give it as "/organization-configuration>" in the example.

Comment: Sadly that was just a copy-paste error. I'll update the question. Good catch.

Comment: See if this link helps you to debug: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir?p0=myPopup&p1=myDraggable&p2=new%2Fisolated%20scope&p3=%3Cdiv%20my-draggable%3D%22draggable%22%20class%3D%22dialog%22%20dialog-title%3D%22My%20Title%22%20is-draggable%3D%22%7B%7Btrue%7D%7D%22%3E

Comment: Wasn't of much use. Have already looked at that error page when it first appeared :/